# How can we get the offset of a caret programatically if it was placed infront of a PsiElement?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I need to get the reference to a `PsiElement` in an IntelliJ Plugin. `getReference()` functions returns null. How can I get this reference by programatically simulating a caret at that position. Is it possible to calculate the position of caret that would be if it was placed after a `PsiElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
PsiUtilCore.getElementAtOffset(@NotNull PsiFile file, int offset)
```

It returns `PsiElement` at the given offset.

Comment: I need its opposite, like can I get what the offset of a caret will be if it were placed at that PsiElement.

Comment: have you checked the `PsiElement` methods? There are plenty of offset-like methods, i.e. to get the `startOffset`